# Permission denied to ruby version using PassengerRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, passenger, virtualhost, phusion

I'm serving three Ruby on Rails apps on one server, two of which are running on the system default ruby 2.0, and one running on ruby 2.2. For the latter I have set the PassengerRuby in my VirtualHost as follows:

```
<VirtualHost 137.154.17.242:80>
  ServerName myappaddress.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myapp/current/public
  RailsEnv production
  PassengerRuby /home/30036712/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin
  <Directory /var/www/html/myapp/current/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I restart the server and refresh the page on the app I get an access denied to ruby 2.2 in my .rvm:

```
*** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /home/30036712/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin: Permission denied (13)
```

Do I need an additional access setting somewhere? The other two apps run fine using ruby 2.0 (and permissions on the .rvm folders are exactly the same)

Answer (score 1):

You specified the Ruby bin *directory*. But you really need to specify the Ruby wrapper *script*. See https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#setting_correct_passenger_ruby_value